# Why blocking direct url access also demolishes Ajax call from a file on the webserver?

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

I want to block Url (external) access to PHP file in the folder "/mi-php/".  So I created a .htaccess file within /mi-php folder with the following codes:

```
<Files *.php>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>
```

Sure, the php files are blocked from directly url access. However, when I try to call this php (/mi-php/jobdata.php) file using Ajax in one file on the webserver as follows:

```
$(document).ready( function () { $.getJSON("/mi-php/jobdata.php", function(data){ etc etc
```

It is also blocked.  I thought calling by another file under the same website root directory is considered "localhost" access.  I guess I am wrong.   But how to make the php file accessible to only my own files under the root directory?

Comment: Do you happen to use IPv6?

Comment: I am not sure about your question.  The webpage has this problem is here `http://magik-info.com/index.php/job-list/`  Not sure about IPv6

Comment: If you try to access it externally, you need to add your external IP there. 127.0.0.1 is only correct when access it on your own computer.

Comment: What do you mean by "local files"?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, "local files" refer to those under my website root directory on the hosting server

Comment: @JohannBauer, I need to make the php files accessible by other files under the website root, but not by external IP address.

Comment: Ah.. no, if you refer to a file witl `/mi-php/jobdata.php` doesn't make it a local call. It only let's you skip writing the full URL. It's still the same domain as the original call.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  there must be ways allowing do this, right?

Comment: @LearnAWK - That's not correct. Using `$_get()` in JS is the same as calling it externally. It's not possible to use Ajax on a file and at the same time block it from external calls. Ajax is the same thing as an external call from the webservers point of view. Javascript runs in the visitors browser .i.e. externally.

Comment: You can use `%{HTTP_REFERER}` in a `RewriteCond` though.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson your explanation makes sense, I really appreciate it. even though didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Are you attempting to only allow access to this folder if you are running a script from the machine running the Apache server?

Comment: @hjpotter92 - That's a good way to make it not to work for a lot of visitors. Many routers/vpns etc remove the referer headers for privacy reasons. And it's very simple to mock a referrer.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, only allow access from files on my web server.

Comment: What version of Apache are you running?

Comment: @RiggsFolly  2.2.31.   My website in on Arvixe.com

Comment: @hjpotter92 Could you please provide an example? I really have no experience on the terms you mentioned.

Comment: The example doesn't solve your issue. I would say, it's not possible to solve this issue with 100% security. There will always be ways to go around any fix.

Comment: I've added an answer with one of the non-hundred-percent-ways you can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see that there are any bullet proof ways of solving this. The only way I can think of is to see if the call is an Ajax call.

```
if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) || strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
    die();
}
```

*Based on David Walsh blog post [here](https://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax).*

You need to add the above snippet in the top of each file you're trying to block. There are two things to consider.

1. Anyone can modify the header of their call and add the above header.
2. Some servers/ajax-clients don't send this header (Apache and jQuery does).

There might be more you can check in your script but this would be a start.

Comment: Your method works! Thank you so much for helping me, even though I don't have the knowledge base to completely understand your comments.  But it is a starting point, as you said. Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

The method I suggested [in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33596516/why-blocking-direct-url-access-also-demolishes-ajax-call-from-a-file-on-the-webs#comment54968361_33596516) would be like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?arvixe\.com/ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^mi-php(/|$) - [F,NC]
```

The above will go in the document root of your httpd server.

Note that a client can send fake headers to bypass these. Also, as [Magnus suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33596516/why-blocking-direct-url-access-also-demolishes-ajax-call-from-a-file-on-the-webs/33597018#comment54968439_33596516), these values might get removed from the request entirely pertaining to users' firewall/ISP settings. Do not rely 100% on this.

---

Another method you can try is, right before the AJAX call, store the following piece of value inside a session variable:

```
<?php $_SESSION['ajax'] = 'allowed';
```

Now, in the files that will be requested with AJAX call, put the following check at the very beginning of each of them:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if( !isset($_SESSION['ajax']) and $_SESSION['ajax'] !== 'allowed' )
        die();
    else
        unset( $_SESSION['ajax'] );
?>
```

Comment: Never trust that the referral-header exist. There are many routers/vpns and firewalls that removes it for privacy reasons.